# How to retrieve whole nested data form multiple document from firebase in flutter

Tags: database, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How can I retrieve the all the data form each uid with their nested field and order them in according to order sent time.

Here is the structure of database

[image]

Comment: "I am not able to do so" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Actually, I dont know how to retrieve nested array data form different Uid.

Comment: The question is a little vague and there is no `order sent time` field showing. If you're meaning `order sent at` that's going to be ambiguous as you could have 5 objects in the `delivery` array with 5 different timestamps, and then the next document could have the same configuration - which time should it be sorted by since every document could have multiple time entries? As far as reading data, that's a separate question (and can be answered by going through the documentation)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `order sent at` field is in the `Delivery` array field, there can be multiple values for each document. In order to sort on a field, there must be a single value for each document.

The easiest way to allow the use-case is to introduce a new top-level field in the document, for example `most recent order sent at`, that you then update whenever you add a `order sent at` value to the `Delivery` array.

Once this field exists, you can order on it in your queries.